# Java Launching another app not working on Windows

Tags: java, process, path, runtime

So, I've been making this app, and I got to a point that I need to launch another app. My current code is:

```
String cmd = String.format("java -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC     -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M     -Djava.library.path=%s -cp %s/*:%sminecraft.jar     net.minecraft.client.main.Main -accessToken 0 -userProperties {} -version     \"Kliens2\" -sessionId2 %s -username %s",wrapper.installPath() + "lib",     wrapper.installPath() + "lib", wrapper.installPath(), token, user);
if(sys.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
    md = String.format("java -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M -Djava.library.path=\"%s\" -cp \"%s/*\":\"%sminecraft.jar\" net.minecraft.client.main.Main -accessToken 0 -userProperties {} -version \"Kliens2\" -sessionId2 %s -username %s",System.getenv("appdata") + "/lib", System.getenv("appdata") + "/lib", System.getenv("appdata") + "/.Kliens2/", token, user);
}
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
```

This works perfectly on Linux, On windows it crashed with 
    Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main

Anyone?

Comment: On Windows, the path separator is semicolon (`;`), not colon (`:`).  Just like the Windows `Path` environment variable.

Comment: Perfect, but I need to keep the * in there. There are a lot of libraries